# Running Chromium Flow on a USB disk to boot on school computers?

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-os

So I gonna make a USB bootable drive of Hexxeh's ChromiumOS Flow. I want this to be able to boot into it on my school computer. The computers use Novel network and each student gets their own login.

Can I use my USB drive to boot into ChromiumOS from the schools computer? I don't need to access the files on my Novel Login.

So can I even do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely school PCs are locked to boot from only one source (HDD?). And any other sources (like USB or LAN) are probably disabled thru BIOS. And probably the BIOS is password locked.

So I assume you'll not be able to boot from USB.

Comment: Argh. My schools pretty lazy so lets hope they forgot to lock the bios...

Comment: Have you ever met school IT teams? Most of them really aren't that sharp. If there is a BIOS passwords, odds are it's easy to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this out](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-google-chrome-os-and-run-on-a-real-computer/) for creating the bootable installation on an USB-drive. Your school's computer have to have booting from removable media enabled though.